# Multiple strategy.exit calls not triggering

Tags: pine-script

I've tried many different ways of setting up trailing stops, max stop loss, and multiple TP levels, and they are always temperamental. Like one trade will work fine, then the next trade wont. The way that they should work seems to be the only way I can't get anything to work properly.

This is an example where it calls for a long, then sets the trailing stop, maximum stop loss, and then take profit levels. The trade enters fine, but nothing else triggers. I use cancel_all to clear everything when any of the other exit conditions are triggered.

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="L1",qty=strategy.default_entry_qty(close*(1-(limit_level/lever)/100))*lever, alert_message=""+AM_ent_lg, limit = close*(1-(limit_level/lever)/100))
strategy.exit("Exit-TSL","Long",trail_price = ts_trig_l,trail_offset = ts_ticks_l,alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
strategy.exit("Exit-SLL","Long",stop=sl_trig_l,trail_price = ts_trig_l,trail_offset = ts_ticks_l,alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
if tp_levels == 1 
    strategy.exit("LongTP1","Long", limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+(tp1/(lever))/100),alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
else if tp_levels == 2
    strategy.exit("LongTP1","Long",qty_percent = tp1q,limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+(tp1/(lever))/100),alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
    strategy.exit("LongTP2","Long",limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+(tp2/(lever))/100),alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
else if tp_levels == 3
    strategy.exit("LongTP1","Long",qty_percent = tp1q,limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+(tp1/(lever))/100),alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
    strategy.exit("LongTP2","Long",qty_percent = tp2q,limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+(tp2/(lever))/100),alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
    strategy.exit("LongTP3","Long",limit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1+(tp3/(lever))/100),alert_message=""+AM_exit_lg)
```

I have tried just entering the position, then having a seperate if statement that checks to see if there is an open trade, which then sets the exit's. Generally these have to be before the entry triggers in the code to work, no idea why. But it doesn't seem to be able to handle all three types. There is always one that doesn't seem to trigger.

I have tried lots of different combos, and I've tried doing the trailing stop monitoring by manual calculation and setting it each candle, but that has the same sort of issues as above, and it can cause significant slippage if you use the strategy.close command rather than strategy.exit.